# How to change AJAX call target when calling from different view/page?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, unit-testing, qunit

I am testing a .js script using Qunit.

I have a static .html test harness that includes the .js "code under test" (CUT) and contains appropriate markup. I am testing using QUnit in another script that is included.
This harness and the test script resides in a project: `Application.UI.Tests.JScript`.

There are AJAX calls in the CUT that have a target relative to the location of the view that uses it.
The views and scripts reside in the conventional folders in an MVC project: `Application.UI`.

The build event of `Application.UI.Tests.JScript` does a `Del` and `XCopy` of the Scripts and Content folders to ensure the tests are running against a copy of the latest version of the CUT.

**Example code:**

```
sendDataToServerViaAjax: function () {
    var dataToSend = somefunctionThatReturnsData();

    $.ajax({
         url: 'actionName'
        , type: 'post'
        , data: dataToSend
        , dataType: 'json'
        , success: function (returnedData) {
            alert('This was received by server: ' + returnedData);
        }
    });
}
```

The actionName goes to an action:

```
[ValidateInput(false)] //TODO for now
public JsonResult actionName(FormCollection formIn)
{
    string jsonData = formIn[0];
    JsonResult result = new JsonResult();
    result.Data = jsonData;
    return result;
}
```

which just returns the data for now and will eventually have calls to proper logic in the Domain layer.

---

**Question:**
How can I make the CUT call the AJAX action on the controller in the running `Application.UI` project from the static .html page in `Application.UI.Tests.JScript` without editing the CUT to include information specific for testing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the `url` value from `actionName` to `/Controller/actionName` will make the url relative to the root of the site e.g.

```
$.ajax({
     url: 'actionName'
    , type: 'post'
    , data: dataToSend
    , dataType: 'json'
    , success: function (returnedData) {
        alert('This was received by server: ' + returnedData);
    }
});
```